# Which package installed postfix as a dependency?

Tags: apt

I have a script that has lots "sudo apt install ..." commands. While running the script I realized that it also installs postfix which I didn't specify. Is there an easy way to identify which package installs postfix?

**Edit:** OK. In my situation the "mailutils" package installs postfix as a virtual package with the name default-mta. `aptitude why postfix` gives the clue. Now I'm gonna use `sudo apt install mailutils postfix-` (note the dash) to install mailutils without installing postfix.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have aptitude installed, you can try

`apt remove postfix --simulate`

- Note the `--simulate` flag. Nothing will actually be removed.

and see what apt wants to remove that requires postfix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `aptitude` installed, you can just do

`aptitude why postfix`

I don't have `postfix` installed, but when I run it on `nullmailer` I get

```
i   lsb-core   Depends  lsb-invalid-mta (>= 11.1.0ubuntu2) | mail-transport-agent
p   nullmailer Provides mail-transport-agent
```